# Error to load a custom class with composer autoload.php

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I'm trying to load a custom class (google_auth.class.php) with the composer autoload.

This is my structure file:

```
/vendor
/lib/src/google_auth.class.php
index.php
autoload.php';
```

this is autoload.php

```
<?php
  return require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

This is my index.php code:

```
<?php
$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'init.php';
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
$auth = new GoogleOauthClass($googleClient);
?>
```

I add this code to my composer.json:

```
"autoload":{
  "psr-4":{
    "GoogleOauth\\": "lib/src/"
  }
}
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`

If I execute: `php index.php` I get this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GoogleOauthClass' not found in /home/oskar/webapps/sourcecode/googlelogin/index.php on line 19
```

If I add to the files this line:

```
 require_once ('lib/src/google_auth.class.php');
```

It works fine.

Thanks.

Oskar

Comment: `vendoer !== vendor`

Comment: Check naming conventions for PSR-4 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: I wrote wrong it here, in my computer I run  "composer init", and "composer require".

Comment: Thanks @JanMares you were right.